# Solution of an linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y(t)$ be the solution to $$y''+ty'-t^2y=0,y(0)=1，y'(0)=0$$
How to prove that $y(t)\gt0 ,\forall t\in\mathbb{R}$?
I can only find that $y(t)$ is an even function, then I have no idea about it.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%5E2y%2Fdt%5E2+%2Bt+dy%2Fdt+-t%5E2+y+%3D+0%2C++y%280%29+%3D+1%2C+dy%280%29%2Fdt+%3D+0

Answer (score 1):

First, let's transform this equation to Sturm–Liouville form
$$
(p(t)y')' - q(t)y = 0,\\
y(0) = 1, y'(0) = 0.
$$
Expanding terms we obtain
$$
\frac{p(t)}{1} = \frac{p'(t)}{t} = \frac{q(t)}{t^2} = f(t)
$$
Solving for $p(t)$ gives
$$
(\log p)' = t \implies p(t) = C e^{t^2/2}
$$
The constant $C$ is redundant so let $C = 1$.

The equation becomes
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left[
e^{t^2/2} y'
\right] - t^2 e^{t^2/2} y = 0.
$$
Now integrating over $[0, s]$ gives
$$
e^{s^2/2} y'(s) - y'(0) = \int_0^s t^2 e^{t^2/2} y(t) dt. \tag{*}
$$
Suppose that $s_0$ is the smallest positive root of $y(s_0) = 0$. The mean value theorem states that exists $s_1 \in (0, s_0)$ such that
$$
y'(s_1) = \frac{y(s_0) - y(0)}{s_0 - 0} = -\frac{1}{s_0}.
$$

Plugging $s = s_1$ into (*) gives a contradiction, since the left hand side is negative and the right hand side is positive. Thus there is no positive root of $y(t) = 0$.